# How do I search for a particular item in my database using Swift and Firebase?

Tags: ios, swift, database, xcode, firebase

So I am building an app where I add certain words to my Firebase Database. When the user enters the word they want to add, I want to check if that word already exists in the database. If it does then I would show an alert. If not, I'll add it to the database. How would I do that with Swift? Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

Here's the database structure:

```
speaktext-6-----
  wordList
    -LWQObIw1PKWJ_B9jNfp
       word: "Water"
       wordType: "Noun"
```

Comment: Can you include your Firebase structure as that will determine an accurate answer. Include it as text please, no images.

Comment: @Jay I updated the question with the data structure. I hope this is what you asked for. Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: @Jay I got it to work! Thanks to Gustavo Vollbrecht. Thanks a lot for your input as well!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to take into account there may be a significant number of words so loading all of the words in will not only be slow as they have to loaded and then iterated over to find the word you are looking for, but it may also overwhelm the devices memory.

A simple solution is a Firebase Query - let Firebase do the heavy lifting and just return the node you want. It will be a LOT faster and won't overwhelm the device.

Here's a function that will tell you if a word exists within your firebase structure

```
func findWord(aWord: String) {
    let ref = self.ref.child("wordList")
    let query = ref.queryOrdered(byChild: "word").queryEqual(toValue: aWord)
    query.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in
        if snapshot.exists() {
            print("found the word")
            //you could expand on this to indicate it was a Noun etc
        } else {
            print("\(aWord) is not in the wordList")
        }
    })
}
```

Also review the [Firebase Sorting and Filtering Data Guide](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/lists-of-data#sorting_and_filtering_data)

*this assumes a structure of

```
root
  wordList
    word_id_0  //created with .childByAutoId
       word: "Water"
```

Comment: Hey. Thanks for the efficient solution. I implemented this but I ran into an error. Here's the description: Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value. The error is on the 2nd line of the code you wrote in your answer (i.e let ref = self.ref.child("wordList"). Could you help me out here as well? Thanks a lot!

Comment: that is because he is using a class reference, you can replace `self` with `Database.database().reference()`

Comment: @ojassethi Gustavo is correct - I have a class var set up that references my Firebase - so from then on, I can use self.ref instead of typing out *let reference = Database.database().reference().* every time.

Comment: I created a new variable in the function which gives the reference to the wordList table and it worked. Thanks a lot to both of you! It helped me a lot.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to make a single event request on the word child, then you can verify if it `.exists()` and it will return if it's there or not.

```
let reference = Database.database().reference().child(<#child#>).child(<#Word#>)

reference.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in

    if snapshot.exists() {
        // handle word existing in database, show alert.
    } else {
        // handle word not existing in database, make a request to set the word in database.
    }
})
```

According to your comments, you wanna iterate through every element on a child, you can do it by doing this:

```
let reference = Database.database().reference().child("wordList")

reference.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in

    if let words = snapshot.value as? [String : [String : Any]] {
            for word in words {
                if let currentWord = word.value["word"] as? String {
                    if currentWord == "YOUR WORD HERE" {
                        // handle word in database.
                        return
                    }
                }
            }

            // handle word NOT in database.

    } else {
        // handle empty array.
    }
})
```

Comment: Hey! Thanks for responding. I tried doing this but it still isn't comparing the word with the database. Here's the code I wrote: 'func checkIfWordExists() {
        let reference = Database.database().reference().child("wordList").child("Word").child(wordTextField.text!)
        reference.observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { (snapshot) in
            if snapshot.exists() {
                self.displayAlert(title: "Error", message: "Word exists already.", buttonMessage: "Okay")
            } else {
                self.addWordToDatabase()
            }
        }
    }'

Comment: Take a look at your modeling, make sure you're looking on the right child, your deepest one should be the word. Also make sure the textField.text is exactly the word in your database.

Comment: I am trying to do that. I have the database URL, which is the database reference. I then have a table called "wordList". Then I have elements with autoID. Each autoID element contains two fields called "Word" and "wordType". Do I have the code right for this model? Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: no, if you have childs by autoID the only way to access them it's having their ID, or iterating through every element on `wordList`

Comment: Oh. That explains a lot. How do I make it go through every element? Thanks again!

Comment: @ojassethi This answer assumes a lot of things about your structure, and if you are using that structure you may want to consider something different. For example; this question assumes you know what *YourChild* is for every word. That's probably not going to a work in a real world app - *YourChild* will probably be generated with childByAutoId which means this answer won't work. An alternate is to use a key: value pair of *word: true* where word is the words stored in Firebase. IN that case again, it won't work. The answerer here should include a structure this answer applies to.

Comment: @GustavoVollbrecht thank you so much for helping me out. The new method worked out perfectly!

Comment: @ojassethi While technically this answer will work, it's probably not a good idea in the long run and will be extremely slow if you have thousands of words. See my answer as an alternate solution.